# 2D Distortion shaders for water effect

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, displacement-mapping

I'm working on Unity, and I'm trying to improve my water.
The water will be seen top down, and I want to apply a shader to it to make it better looking.
I understand the concept of distortion shaders and using noise to make the maps for the displacement.

However I don't know what is the best option when implementing this.

-When using noise for this effect, should I create this noise texture each drawing cycle?

-How can I keep the distortion animation smooth? Since noise is random, how can I make a smooth animation for the distortion?

-Be it calculated each cycle, or having a precalculated set of distortion maps, how does the shader recieve this info? Each cycle the shader recieves a different distortion map? Or does the shader hold all the distortion maps?

I have seen tutorials and guides, but they explain it on a high level, leaving a lot of gaps in the process, and not being very experienced with shaders, I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Are you sure you need a displacement shader? From the description you just need a water surface shader, emulating the waves and reflections, but keeping the water surface flat.

Comment: I think I misused the term. Distortion shader is what I need.